# How can I improve my OOP?

Tags: c++, ruby, oop

I'm writing this after doing searches and not finding much useful answers. I know the basic of programming, like context (loops, conditionals), basic ideas (classes, instances, inheritance.) and I'd like to improve on my OOP. The thing is when I look at open source projects, they seem very overwhelming because there is so much going on. How can I improve and learn the concepts of OOP without jumping into a huge project. I'd like to go in steps because I always learn best when things are broken down and not thrown at me all at once. Are there any resources you can share? Or any advice in general would be really appreciated. I want to take the next step, but just don't know where to begin. How did you guys go about improving your skills, how did you take the next step? Right now I'm focused on C++ and Ruby.

Comment: Consider asking this question on a different site, like Quora. It would be welcome there. Here we tend to prefer questions that are less opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

OOP is an idea and doesn't depend on your programming language.
You can learn various design patterns to improve your OOP.